# I can't understand why I get this result when I bitwise OR a short and char

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit

Could someone please explain why I get this result when I bitwise OR two numbers? I'm really confused.

```
signed char signedChar = -64;       // This is now -64, or 1100 0000
unsigned char unsignedChar = signedChar; // This is now 196, or 1100 0000 (The same)

short signedShort = 0;     // This is now 0000 0000 0000 0000
signedShort |= signedChar;   // This is now -64, not 196
```

What I expected to happen was this, I or'ed signedShort and signedChar, which is:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 or'ed with
          1100 0000
0000 0000 1100 0000 result 
equalling 196.
```

But instead I got -64

Why does this OR operation add a one at the beginning? I totally expected something different.

Thanks.

Comment: Arithmetic conversions?

Comment: Because of sign extension.

Comment: @Kerrek Oh, so you're saying that before it does the operation it promotes the char to a short, and then the short has a leading 1, and then does the bitwise OR? Is there any way to just add the bits to the short?

Comment: It's more subtle than that. Everything is promoted to `int` in fact. Usually you should a) work with unsigned types, and then b) truncate the result.

Comment: @Kerrek Would it be promoted to a 64 bit int if doing it on a long long for example?

Comment: Intregral promotions only go up to `int`. The types with greater conversion rank don't promote.

Comment: "But instead I got -64" - How do you know? See [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: ORing something with zero doesn't change its value. So if you OR 0 with -64, you get -64. This is no different from `signedShort = signedChar;`.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `signedShort |= signedChar;` is interpreted as

```
signedShort = signedShort | signedChar;
```

Both operands of the `|` operator are promoted to `int`, the bitwise or operation is performed on these promoted values and the resulted is converted to the type of the destination, `short`.

Hence the value of `signedChar`, `-64` is extended as an `int` with the same value. Or-ing to `0` does not change the value.  Converting it to `short` also keeps the value because `-64` is within the range of `short`, so the result is `-64`.

Note that this does not depend on the actual representation of integers. You assume 2s complement in your question, but it would produce the same result with sign+magnitude or 1s complement.

Answer (score 1):

Signed types with negative values will be extended with ones. An unsigned type will be extended with zeros.

Your unsigned char gets promoted to signed, since that is what you are performing operations with.

Signed is a promotion from unsigned

In your example:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 or'ed with
1111 1111 1100 0000
1111 1111 1100 0000 result
```

Comment: you mean signed types with negative signs will be extended with ones. Otherwise that'll be a hell of a mess, if values suddenly start to mutate when being extended.

Answer (score -1):

That is how basically [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) arithmetic works. To preserve sign of a value, a special operation [Sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) is applied during conversion.

Let's take a simpler example of -10:

```
signed char signedChar = -10; // bits: 11110110b
signed short signedShort = signedChar; // bits: 1111111111110110b
```

Why not 1000000000000110b as you seem expected it to be? Because 1000000000000110b is -32762 in two's complement :-(

Comment: The code does not print signed values, but invokes undefined behaviour. `printf` expects an `unsigned int` for `%x`, but you pass an `int`